# add input user values from while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

I´m a complete beginner and doing an assignment. The different weights for the parcel have different prices, the user has to be able to input the amount of parcels and their individual weight and the program has to tell the total price of all the parcels. This is what i´ve got so far,(i don´t know what but something seems off) i can´t seem to figure out how to make the total price the sum of all the different prices of the parcels (p.s not allowed to use for-loops). Appreciate any help or advice and thanks in advance.

```
parcel = int(input("How many parcels do you want to send?"))
i = 1
while i < parcel+1:
  print("State the weight for parcel",i,":")
  weight = int(input())
  if (i == parcel):
    break
  i += 1
if weight < 2:
    price = 30
elif weight == 2 or weight < 6:
    price = 28
elif weight == 6 or weight < 12:
    price = 25
elif weight >= 12:
    price = 23
tot_price = 
print("The total price will be:",tot_price)
```

Comment: How do you increment a variable? How are you incrementing `i`? Consider that. Since this is homework I don't want to give too much.

Comment: I can´t put my finger on what is wrong with it, i can tell that i looks a bit off but i just don´t know how to fix it. Completely understand not wanting to give too much, i appreciate all help, if it´s not too bothersome i would also love to read up on some recommended sources on this topic myself @CL40

Answer (score 1):

```
# All prices of each parcel
list_of_prices = []

# Ask the user to input the number of parcels
parcel_count = int(input("How many parcels do you want to send? "))

count = 1

# Loop through the number of parcels, asking for the weight of each
while count <= parcel_count+1:
    weight = int(input(f"Please input the weight for parcel {count}: "))

    if weight < 2:
        price = 30
    elif 2 <= weight < 6:
        price = 28
    elif 6 <= weight < 12:
        price = 25
    elif weight >= 12:
        price = 23

    list_of_prices.append(int(price))      # add the price to the list

    count += 1

# sum() adds up all the numbers in the list of prices
total_price = sum(list_of_prices)
print("The total price will be:", total_price)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately i wasn´t allowed to use for-loops and in my original code there´s something wrong with the increments which i can´t figure out.  would appreciate any tips, thank you! @haydso

Comment: ah, I see, this shouldn't be too much of an issue as I can simply replace a for loop with an while loop + counter. Let me edit the code to show you what I mean

Comment: @M J, I changed the code from a for loop to a while loop it should do the same